# Caching in WCF Service?

Tags: html, wcf, caching

I am developing a HTML5 Web application. I am using WCF service and SQL Server. 
I need to cache data on WCF service level. I read about ASP.NET caching but it is not support in WCF service.

Please suggest.

Comment: System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not able to use it in my code. I got only System.Runtime. Caching isn't coming. Do i need to install any DLL or anything else?

Comment: You need to be targeting .Net 4 or later and add a reference to System.Runtime.Caching

Comment: Thank you Stuartd. Now I am able to use it. I will use it and let you know whether it will work for me or not.

Comment: Stuartd is there any data memory limit of MemoryCache??

Comment: You configure the memory allowance [in config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or in code.